# Are Researchers at Private Companies Allowed to Publish Papers?

Tags: publications

I'm an academic researcher with a very good publication track record in computer science.

I'm considering the possibility of applying for a research position at a well known telecommunications company with a large research department. But I still would like to have the possibility of publishing theoretical work.

1) Are researchers in private companies usually allowed to publish theoretical work produced in cooperation with researchers outside the company?

2) Are researchers in private companies usually allowed to publish theoretical work produced inside the company?

Comment: This is likely off-topic here as it is about a company. But the place to get an answer is from Erickson's HR office. Or you could read the contract if you have one. Just guessing, though, is that you will give up a lot of IP rights to the company, including non-compete and trade secret rules, etc.

Comment: For future reference, see the Help Center to see what questions work well here and which are likely to be closed: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help.  Anyway. Welcome to Academia.

Comment: Actually the issue is the same. There is another site here that is better suited to such questions: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ and possibly others.

Comment: As a researcher in industry, I strongly believe that this question is on topic and appropriate.

Comment: Do you mean, are they permitted to by the academy or by their employers?

Comment: As someone who has worked for the research arm of a multi-national company, publishing is definitely a possibility.  However, it is not a priority.  Patents are much more valuable.  Consequently, any paper/idea must first be vetted by a committee and lawyers.  If it is valuable to the company, then a patent must be filed first before any paper can be submitted to a conference/journal -- this process can take a while and can be frustrating if one is aiming for a conference deadline.   This is even worst if the paper has a student author, meaning the patent process could delay any publications.

Comment: Continuing on my previous comment, if an idea becomes a trade secret and it involves a student, then the said student might not be able to graduate.  Note, a company may have collaboration with a university or you might continue to collaborate with your current university, and hence, students may be involved in your research.  In this situation, great care must be taken.

Answer (score 26):

Speaking as a researcher at a private for-profit company, who also publishes frequently, it all depends on the nature of the business model and the position.

Most people at companies do not publish, either because the company has no interest in publishing or because their particular job doesn't involve much of scientific interest. For companies that are involved in cutting edge work, however, scientific publishing can gain credibility and visibility for the organization just like it does for people at universities. This is the case for the company I work for, particularly given that many of our projects are federally funded research where the government is paying us in part to disseminate knowledge.

Nor is there any necessary conflict between protecting intellectual property and publishing. The three main strategies for protecting IP are copyright, patent, and trade secret. Of those, only trade secret is incompatible with publishing, and it is generally the most fragile and least used in any case.

The biggest obstacle to publishing in private industry is simply priority and time. Writing a manuscript is a lot of work, and if management doesn't see much benefit, they will likely want you to use those hours for things more directly connected to the bottom line. You might be able to publish out of hours, but that can be a more complex negotiation.

Bottom line: it really depends on the particular circumstances. The best way to know if you will be able to publish is to look at whether others in the group you are joining publish. If so, you probably can. If not, there are likely major obstacles, whether formal or merely pragmatic.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer fails to make an essential point. Most companies take control of the decision to publish for their employees. There is a gate between you and publishing, even for work not done on company time. The fact that the gate will be opened for you in most cases doesn't change the fact of the gate, nor the fact that its default position is _closed_. You give up your _freedom to decide_ what to publish and yield it to your employer. You can decide whether that is good or bad, but you can't make it _not a fact_ by wishing it weren't true nor by finessing the outcome.

Comment: @Buffy I don't dispute your statement---it's just that in my experience as a private researcher, it is pragmatically rarely relevant.  If you are in a publications-friendly position, then the system will be tractable and generally pose much less of an obstacle than peer-review or collaborators.  If not, then the formal permissions process is probably much less of a barrier than "Why did you spend 80 hours on this crap when you could have been doing your job?"

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to answer your question unless you specify the company name. Many companies are very active in research, and many companies are not. As you are not an employee yet, you cannot ask the HR, but you can search.

For example, if you [search for "deep learning" in ACM](https://dl.acm.org/results.cfm?within=owners.owner%3DHOSTED&srt=_score&query=deep%20learning&Go.x=23&Go.y=5), and click on `institutions` on the left menu, you can see there is Microsoft, IBM and Google there. ACM also keeps company profiles, so you know what topic they are interested in, for example this is [profile of Google](https://dl.acm.org/inst_page.cfm?id=60006191).

Someone (from Amazon) just told me that Amazon had nearly turned [FLoC](https://www.floc2018.org/) into a private Amazon event. The conferences at FloC are highly theoretical, and among the most prestigious in logic.

But actually, you don't need to ask this question, as in the companies that are active in research, the directors/principal engineers etc are often former professors, and we followers immediately know where big shots move :-)

---

Update: thanks @Anyon for pointing out that the company name was editted out. Yes, that company does publish, see [its profile](https://dl.acm.org/inst_page.cfm?id=60004661) in ACM.

Comment: Psst. If you check the edit history of the OP you'll find the company name. It was likely edited out so that the question wouldn't depend too much on personal factors.

Answer (score -4):

In general terms, if the publication is, in any way, related to the company's business it will probably be contractually forbidden unless specific permission is given for the paper.

Signing on with a company that depends on IP usually means that anything you produce is theirs, not yours. Read the contract to be sure. Some contracts try to bind you forever, even when you leave the company. The legality of these can be challenged and they may be illegal in some places.

However, if your other work is completely unrelated, then it is probably ok, but it needs to be "released" by whoever is responsible for IP control at the company.

On rare occasions (THE WOZ at HP, for example), a company will give permission to do something that would otherwise be prohibited, but normally because they lack sufficient insight to see the consequences. If they are happy enough to make an exception, make sure you have it in writing - signed and maybe notarized.

Comment: But it really depends on the company. Google, for instance, publishes a lot in the Machine Learning field.

Comment: @Adrian, I assume you mean Google employees. But I'd be willing to bet that each one has a release for each such paper and that the contracts give the company the power to deny publication.

Comment: I assume that too, I just meant that some companies allow their employees to publish (some) of their work.

Comment: @Adrian, I think many do, actually. I know  a lot of IBM employees that publish (with permission). But it is the company that gets to decide usually, not the researcher. I'll also note that even some universities have restrictive contracts - especially for patents.

Comment: My employer (not Google or IBM) can certainly deny publication if it is inappropriate for the needs of the business, but on the other hand it has a formal procedure in place to *approve* papers for external publication, conference presentations, etc, and there is a steady stream of papers (of the order of 10 to 100 per year) that are approved for publication.

Comment: Buffy - That first line is pretty overdone, I think. While GE Labs, Bell Labs, and IBM Research are perhaps not as prominent as they used to be in technical fields, one can still find many papers from companies in different venues. And, those papers deal directly with the company business. For example, in the semiconductor industry (chip manufacturers and equipment manufacturers), such papers are critical to their ability to show the world what they can do. Few if any in Phys. Rev., but IEEE conference proceedings for sure.

Comment: @JonCuster, I made a small edit. But I'll wager that all of those papers have a release from the company. And all of those companies have a specific contractual clause requiring release. They would be foolish not to. In particular, an "open" policy here could get in the way of patent filings. Don't lose track of the main message here. When you work for a company it is highly likely that they own all your IP, whether produced on company time or not, and many try to own it in perpetuity.

Comment: Oh - absolutely. But if that is your line, you need to consider all the US government labs as well - they all have processes to allow release of information including publications. Scientists are allowed to publish, they just need to follow the rules.

Comment: The US government is a bit different. Most of what is produced there is considered public domain as it is produced with the public's money. I don't know all the rules, but that is the general underlying theory. The government cannot patent anything, for example. Some agencies (EPA, Interior,...)  have recently tried to suppress some research but courts seem skeptical about that.

Comment: @JonCuster. See the above comment. There are national security exceptions to openness, of course. If someone on the Manhattan project had published, for example, they'd have been shot.

Comment: It isn't national security per se - yes making sure it is not classified is part of it, making sure it isn't patentable is part of it, but formal internal review and quality control is also part of it. And, generally, that has been true at every non-university place I've worked or interacted with. It is a hurdle, yet my groups over the years have managed to publish many many papers (and I've got the auto-generated emails from the review process to prove it!).

Comment: @Buffy You're still much overemphasizing a distinction that is in practice often quite minimal in impact. Many university academics also accept similar pre-publication review processes through collaborations and consortia.

Comment: @JonCuster To build on what you've said: a nice example of this is [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/). Assured quality in results is a critical part of their mission, so every publication goes through a rather strict internal technical review before submission is allowed.

Comment: @jakebeal, the question was about companies, originally a specific company. So, I just addressed that. One of my comments above addresses the university question. I hope none of the comments here are trying to imply that publishing without permission if you are in a company is just fine and go ahead. That would be a serious error. Like I said, check the contract. Ask if necessary.